# How to check if a function returns response object

Tags: python, django, response

I have a function which calls another function and proceeds on the result of the called function.

What I want to do is to check if the function being called returns a `response` object or not and then use it in the existing function.

I tried to use `isinstance` but I am not getting what arg to use.

```
def func(request):
    return HttpResponse('xyz')

def check_func(request):

    res = func()
    # Here I want to check if res is response object or not
    # And continue accordingly
```

Do suggest some ways to check .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can test if it is an instance of [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse), it is the [base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) for all response types.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def check_func(request):

    res = func()
    if isinstance(res, HttpResponse):
       #do something
```